# comparing equations and equating the ratios of their coefficients?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

so I had to convert a general form equation**(3x+4y-12=0)** into its perpendicular form **(xcost+using=p)**. for this we compared the two equations and as they are both equalivent equations, the coefficients of **x, y and xy^0** were equal. but then we also equated the ratios of these coefficients, and considered them all to be equal to k**(cost/3=sint/3=p/12=k)**. what I don't understand is that if the ratios of each of these coefficients is 1, why are we taking it equal to k and then solving for k? why didn't we just take as 1?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.